# Why are all google website suddenly giving untrusted certificate warnings in my Firefox v10?

Tags: windows-7, dns, ip, hijack, firefox

Today, I am suddenly getting the untrusted website error for all Google websites, but not for any other.  Internet Explorer gives no such error.  Reboot of this Windows 7 computer does not help.

Is this some kind of virus infection that is hijacking DNS resolution away from Google to some spoofer?

How can I resolve this issue and get Google websites working again normally?

If I manually enter a Google IP Address, the page loads correctly.

Comment: Did you determine that google IP by normal DNS resolution from your machine? Do you have a tool to check what outgoing connections Firefox makes?

Comment: No, I used yahoo to search for an ip address posted on a website. But I also tried doing ping from DOS prompt and tried that address too and it worked fine. What tool allows you to check the outgoing connections from Firefox?

Comment: do you or your office have a proxy server?

Comment: I'm using VPN at all times, but now the issue has mysteriously gone away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible reason is an incorrect date (year, for example) on the computer. So browser considers SSL certificates expired or not yet valid.

Comment: this would make sense if was occurring in both browsers perhaps but the OP claims it only occurs in Firefox